How can I implement a nested repeater control in an Elementor widget to add features to pricing plans without causing the repeater to add a new plan?
 protected function register_controls() {
          // Start a section for the pricing plans
          $this->start_controls_section(
              'section_pricing_plans',
              [
                  'label' => esc_html__('Pricing Plans', 'apct-pricing-card-widget'),
                  'tab' => Controls_Manager::TAB_CONTENT,
              ]
          );
      
          // Create a repeater instance for pricing plans
          $plan_repeater = new \Elementor\Repeater();
      
          $plan_repeater->add_control(
              'plan_name',
              [
                  'label' => esc_html__('Plan Name', 'apct-pricing-card-widget'),
                  'type' => Controls_Manager::TEXT,
                  'default' => esc_html__('Basic', 'apct-pricing-card-widget'),
                  'label_block' => true,
              ]
          );
      
          $plan_repeater->add_control(
              'plan_price',
              [
                  'label' => esc_html__('Plan Price', 'apct-pricing-card-widget'),
                  'type' => Controls_Manager::TEXT,
                  'default' => '9.99',
              ]
          );
      
          $plan_repeater->add_control(
              'plan_description',
              [
                  'label' => esc_html__('Plan Description', 'apct-pricing-card-widget'),
                  'type' => Controls_Manager::TEXTAREA,
                  'default' => esc_html__('For beginner use', 'apct-pricing-card-widget'),
              ]
          );
      
          // Create a repeater for features inside the plan repeater
          $feature_repeater = new \Elementor\Repeater();
      
          $feature_repeater->add_control(
              'feature_text',
              [
                  'label' => esc_html__('Feature Text', 'apct-pricing-card-widget'),
                  'type' => Controls_Manager::TEXT,
                  'default' => esc_html__('Feature Item', 'apct-pricing-card-widget'),
                  'label_block' => true,
              ]
          );
      
          // Adding features list to the plan repeater, ensuring it's nested correctly
          $plan_repeater->add_control(
              'features_list',
              [
                  'label' => esc_html__('Plan Features', 'apct-pricing-card-widget'),
                  'type' => Controls_Manager::REPEATER,
                  'fields' => $feature_repeater->get_controls(), // Get controls for features
                  'title_field' => '{{{ feature_text }}}',
              ]
          );
      
          // Add the main pricing plans repeater to the section
          $this->add_control(
              'plans_list',
              [
                  'label' => esc_html__('Pricing Plans', 'apct-pricing-card-widget'),
                  'type' => Controls_Manager::REPEATER,
                  'fields' => $plan_repeater->get_controls(), // Make sure to get plan-level controls
                  'title_field' => '{{{ plan_name }}}',
                  'default' => [
                      [
                          'plan_name' => esc_html__('Basic Plan', 'apct-pricing-card-widget'),
                          'plan_price' => '9.99',
                          'plan_description' => esc_html__('For beginner use', 'apct-pricing-card-widget'),
                      ],
                      // Include default plans if needed
                  ],
              ]
          );
      
          $this->end_controls_section();
      }
    
        protected function render() {
            $settings = $this->get_settings_for_display();
            ?>
            <div class="apct_wrapper">
                <div class="apct_header">
                    <?php foreach ($settings['plans_list'] as $index => $item): ?>
                        <label class="apct_tab <?php echo ($index === 0) ? 'active' : ''; ?>">
                            <?php echo esc_html($item['plan_name']); ?>
                        </label>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <div class="apct_slider"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="apct_card-area">
                    <div class="apct_cards">
                        <?php foreach ($settings['plans_list'] as $item): ?>
                            <div class="apct_row">
                                <div class="apct_price-container">
                                    <div class="price-details">
                                        <span class="currency">$</span>
                                        <span class="amount"><?php echo esc_html($item['plan_price']); ?></span>
                                        <span class="duration">/mon</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <p><?php echo esc_html($item['plan_description']); ?></p>
                                </div>
                                <ul class="apct_features">
                                    <?php if (!empty($item['features_list'])): ?>
                                        <?php foreach ($item['features_list'] as $feature): ?>
                                            <li>
                                                <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
                                                <span><?php echo esc_html($feature['feature_text']); ?></span>
                                            </li>
                                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="apct_button">Choose plan</a>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
    
        protected function _content_template() {
            ?>
            <div class="apct_wrapper">
                <div class="apct_header">
                    <# _.each( settings.plans_list, function( item, index ) { #>
                        <label class="apct_tab <# if ( index === 0 ) { #>active<# } #>">
                            {{{ item.plan_name }}}
                        </label>
                    <# }); #>
                    <div class="apct_slider"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="apct_card-area">
                    <div class="apct_cards">
                        <# _.each( settings.plans_list, function( item ) { #>
                            <div class="apct_row">
                                <div class="apct_price-container">
                                    <div class="price-details">
                                        <span class="currency">$</span>
                                        <span class="amount">{{{ item.plan_price }}}</span>
                                        <span class="duration">/mon</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <p>{{{ item.plan_description }}}</p>
                                </div>
                                <ul class="apct_features">
                                    <# _.each( item.features_list, function( feature ) { #>
                                        <li>
                                            <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
                                            <span>{{{ feature.feature_text }}}</span>
                                        </li>
                                    <# }); #>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        <# }); #>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="apct_button">Choose plan</a>
            </div>
            <?php
        }


I am making elementor widget in it I am adding pricing plan with
repeater control and in each plan there are features also for these
features I want to add repeater control can anyone tell me the
solution for nested repeater I have made it in my code to use the
method but there is a problem that when I add a new feature from the
repeater with features, it also adds a new plan.

